# Error R Studio Knit HTML with install.packages line

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

I am a new user to RStudio, and have encountered an error when using a .rmd file and Knit HTML

If I have an install.packages line:

```
install.packages('ggplot2');
library(ggplot2);
```

when I click Knit HTML, an error is returned:

> Error in contrib.url(repos, "source") : trying to use CRAN without
>   setting a mirror calls: ... withVisible -> eval -> eval ->
>   install.packages -> contrib.url Execution halted

I was able to work around this using:

```
if (!require('ggplot2')) 
{
  install.packages('ggplot2');
  library(ggplot2);
}
```

If I'm writing a .rmd, do I need to use the `if (!require(` line every time I install a new package? Is there a way to avoid this so I can write `install.packages(` only?

Comment: Did you try  doing something like: `install.packages("ggplot2", repos = 'http://cran.us.r-project.org')`?

Comment: Why do you need an `install.packages` line? Do you really want to reinstall the package every time you compile the Rmd? Normally you'd install the packages in a separate interactive session and just use `library` in your Rmd.

Comment: As @hrbrmstr suggested, it works well if you set the `repos` argument, I've just tested it.

Comment: I do not always set the CRAN mirror. When I do, I set the cloud mirror http://cran.rstudio.com :)

Comment: Thank you, hrbrmstr and yihui, both of your suggestions worked perfectly! Is it possible to set cran.rstudio.com as a default? Or does it need to be written in the code each time?

Comment: Nick, I add this code in there because I am learning R and RStudio alongside a friend, so I want to share everything I do so that he can easily follow along. I can definitely work around this, like you said, by installing packages separately and then just make a note of it somewhere. For the sake of clear instructions, however, I wanted to make my document as easy to follow as possible.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need `install.package()` line everytime.

Normally you should install packages in console or a separate interactive session or delete that line after installation of that library (here it's ggplot).

Just use library(ggplot2)

```
  library(ggplot2);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for correcting me , I wanted to mention about removal of install.package(). There is no need to to use if statement as far as I know.

Answer (score 4):

I was also getting same error while using the Knit document and I did below things in the R script :

1. Run the command in console to set your default repository :
   options(repos=structure(c(CRAN="http://cran.r-project.org")))
2. Add the below code in your R studio :
   options(repos="https://cran.rstudio.com" )
3. Add the url reference for packages needed, for example :
   install.packages("pscl", repos = "https://cran.rstudio.com")